# change labels in a view using a tableview

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, datasource, tableview

First look at this [screenshot](http://www.flickr.com/photos/74322780@N08/8106422075/in/photostream) please. What I want to do is when I click on a cell in the little tableview on the right. Then the labels should change to some other data. I am using a custom controller for my datasource and delegate. I'm setting the controller in my viewDidLoad.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    
    tabelPlayers=[[tblPlayersDataSourceDelegate alloc]init];
    tblPlayers.dataSource=tabelPlayers;
    tblPlayers.delegate=tabelPlayers;
    [tabelPlayers setTableSource:_playersArray];
}
```

In this tblPlayersDataSourceDelegate I do this for my didSelectCellAtIndexPath

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  Team *player = [_tableSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    PlayerDetailController *detail = [[PlayerDetailController alloc]init];
    [detail setStrNaam:player.name];
    [detail reloadInputViews];
}
```

But it doesn't change anything. Can somebody help me ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right, what you're trying to do is change the information on the left labels according to the selected player from the little table view on the right.

I don't fully understand your code but what I would do as a general structure to achieve the same result as you are describing you want would be to:

1. Create an NSDictionary (could be in a *.plist file) that contains "Items" (inner NSDictionary's).
2. Each "Item" contains keys (player age, player's number or whatever).

The little table on the right will use another NSArray that will be constructed from the main NSArray keys:

```
NamesArray = [mainPlayersDictionary allKeys];
```

Whenever a row is selected in your small tableview you simply load all the labels according to the keys in your main NSDictionary:

```
[ageLabel setText: [[mainPlayersDictionary objectAtIndex:selectedRowIndex] objectForKey:plAge];
[pNumLable setText:[[mainPlayersDictionary objectAtIndex:selectedRowIndex] objectForKey:pNum];
```

And your set. Hope that helps.